# How to retrieve values from JSON nested array?

Tags: android, json, google-geocoding-api

I'm using [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) in my Android application. And I have to retrieve value of long-name key from address-componant JSON array.

Following are JSON structure :

```
     {
   "results":[
      {
         "address_components":[
            {
               "long_name":"285",
               "short_name":"285",
               "types":[
                  "street_number"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Bedford Avenue",
               "short_name":"Bedford Ave",
               "types":[
                  "route"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Williamsburg",
               "short_name":"Williamsburg",
               "types":[
                  "neighborhood",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Brooklyn",
               "short_name":"Brooklyn",
               "types":[
                  "sublocality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"New York",
               "short_name":"New York",
               "types":[
                  "locality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Kings",
               "short_name":"Kings",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_2",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"New York",
               "short_name":"NY",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"United States",
               "short_name":"US",
               "types":[
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"11211",
               "short_name":"11211",
               "types":[
                  "postal_code"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"285 Bedford Avenue, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
         "geometry":{
            "location":{
               "lat":40.71412890,
               "lng":-73.96140740
            },
            "location_type":"ROOFTOP",
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":40.71547788029149,
                  "lng":-73.96005841970849
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":40.71277991970850,
                  "lng":-73.96275638029151
               }
            }
         },
         "types":[
            "street_address"
         ]
      },
      {
         "address_components":[
            {
               "long_name":"Grand St - Bedford Av",
               "short_name":"Grand St - Bedford Av",
               "types":[
                  "bus_station",
                  "transit_station",
                  "establishment"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Williamsburg",
               "short_name":"Williamsburg",
               "types":[
                  "neighborhood",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Brooklyn",
               "short_name":"Brooklyn",
               "types":[
                  "sublocality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Kings",
               "short_name":"Kings",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_2",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"New York",
               "short_name":"NY",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"United States",
               "short_name":"US",
               "types":[
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"11211",
               "short_name":"11211",
               "types":[
                  "postal_code"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"Grand St - Bedford Av, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
         "geometry":{
            "location":{
               "lat":40.7143210,
               "lng":-73.9611510
            },
            "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":40.71566998029149,
                  "lng":-73.95980201970849
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":40.71297201970850,
                  "lng":-73.96249998029151
               }
            }
         },
         "types":[
            "bus_station",
            "transit_station",
            "establishment"
         ]
      },
      {
         "address_components":[
            {
               "long_name":"Grand St - Bedford Av",
               "short_name":"Grand St - Bedford Av",
               "types":[
                  "bus_station",
                  "transit_station",
                  "establishment"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Williamsburg",
               "short_name":"Williamsburg",
               "types":[
                  "neighborhood",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Brooklyn",
               "short_name":"Brooklyn",
               "types":[
                  "sublocality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Kings",
               "short_name":"Kings",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_2",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"New York",
               "short_name":"NY",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"United States",
               "short_name":"US",
               "types":[
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"11211",
               "short_name":"11211",
               "types":[
                  "postal_code"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"Grand St - Bedford Av, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
         "geometry":{
            "location":{
               "lat":40.7146840,
               "lng":-73.9615630
            },
            "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":40.71603298029149,
                  "lng":-73.96021401970850
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":40.71333501970850,
                  "lng":-73.96291198029151
               }
            }
         },
         "types":[
            "bus_station",
            "transit_station",
            "establishment"
         ]
      },
      {
         "address_components":[
            {
               "long_name":"Bedford Av - Grand St",
               "short_name":"Bedford Av - Grand St",
               "types":[
                  "bus_station",
                  "transit_station",
                  "establishment"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Williamsburg",
               "short_name":"Williamsburg",
               "types":[
                  "neighborhood",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Brooklyn",
               "short_name":"Brooklyn",
               "types":[
                  "sublocality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Kings",
               "short_name":"Kings",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_2",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"New York",
               "short_name":"NY",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"United States",
               "short_name":"US",
               "types":[
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"11211",
               "short_name":"11211",
               "types":[
                  "postal_code"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"Bedford Av - Grand St, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
         "geometry":{
            "location":{
               "lat":40.714710,
               "lng":-73.9609990
            },
            "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":40.71605898029150,
                  "lng":-73.95965001970849
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":40.71336101970850,
                  "lng":-73.96234798029150
               }
            }
         },
         "types":[
            "bus_station",
            "transit_station",
            "establishment"
         ]
      },
      {
         "address_components":[
            {
               "long_name":"Williamsburg",
               "short_name":"Williamsburg",
               "types":[
                  "neighborhood",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Brooklyn",
               "short_name":"Brooklyn",
               "types":[
                  "sublocality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"New York",
               "short_name":"New York",
               "types":[
                  "locality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Kings",
               "short_name":"Kings",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_2",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"New York",
               "short_name":"NY",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"United States",
               "short_name":"US",
               "types":[
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"Williamsburg, Brooklyn, NY, USA",
         "geometry":{
            "bounds":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":40.72517730,
                  "lng":-73.9364980
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":40.69793290,
                  "lng":-73.96984499999999
               }
            },
            "location":{
               "lat":40.70644610,
               "lng":-73.95361629999999
            },
            "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":40.72517730,
                  "lng":-73.9364980
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":40.69793290,
                  "lng":-73.96984499999999
               }
            }
         },
         "types":[
            "neighborhood",
            "political"
         ]
      },
      {
         "address_components":[
            {
               "long_name":"11211",
               "short_name":"11211",
               "types":[
                  "postal_code"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Brooklyn",
               "short_name":"Brooklyn",
               "types":[
                  "sublocality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"New York",
               "short_name":"New York",
               "types":[
                  "locality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"New York",
               "short_name":"NY",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"United States",
               "short_name":"US",
               "types":[
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
         "geometry":{
            "bounds":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":40.72800890,
                  "lng":-73.92072990
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":40.69763590,
                  "lng":-73.97616690
               }
            },
            "location":{
               "lat":40.71800360,
               "lng":-73.96537150000002
            },
            "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":40.72800890,
                  "lng":-73.92072990
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":40.69763590,
                  "lng":-73.97616690
               }
            }
         },
         "types":[
            "postal_code"
         ]
      },
      {
         "address_components":[
            {
               "long_name":"Kings",
               "short_name":"Kings",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_2",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"New York",
               "short_name":"NY",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"United States",
               "short_name":"US",
               "types":[
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"Kings, NY, USA",
         "geometry":{
            "bounds":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":40.7394460,
                  "lng":-73.83336509999999
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":40.56956370,
                  "lng":-74.04397190
               }
            },
            "location":{
               "lat":40.65287620,
               "lng":-73.95949399999999
            },
            "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":40.7394460,
                  "lng":-73.83336509999999
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":40.56956370,
                  "lng":-74.04397190
               }
            }
         },
         "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
         ]
      },
      {
         "address_components":[
            {
               "long_name":"Brooklyn",
               "short_name":"Brooklyn",
               "types":[
                  "sublocality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"New York",
               "short_name":"New York",
               "types":[
                  "locality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Kings",
               "short_name":"Kings",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_2",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"New York",
               "short_name":"NY",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"United States",
               "short_name":"US",
               "types":[
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"Brooklyn, NY, USA",
         "geometry":{
            "bounds":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":40.7394460,
                  "lng":-73.83336509999999
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":40.5510420,
                  "lng":-74.056630
               }
            },
            "location":{
               "lat":40.650,
               "lng":-73.950
            },
            "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":40.7394460,
                  "lng":-73.83336509999999
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":40.5510420,
                  "lng":-74.056630
               }
            }
         },
         "types":[
            "sublocality",
            "political"
         ]
      },
      {
         "address_components":[
            {
               "long_name":"New York",
               "short_name":"New York",
               "types":[
                  "locality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"New York",
               "short_name":"NY",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"United States",
               "short_name":"US",
               "types":[
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"New York, NY, USA",
         "geometry":{
            "bounds":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":40.91524140,
                  "lng":-73.70027209999999
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":40.4959080,
                  "lng":-74.25908790
               }
            },
            "location":{
               "lat":40.71435280,
               "lng":-74.00597309999999
            },
            "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":40.91524140,
                  "lng":-73.70027209999999
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":40.4959080,
                  "lng":-74.25573489999999
               }
            }
         },
         "types":[
            "locality",
            "political"
         ]
      },
      {
         "address_components":[
            {
               "long_name":"New York",
               "short_name":"NY",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"United States",
               "short_name":"US",
               "types":[
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"New York, USA",
         "geometry":{
            "bounds":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":45.0158650,
                  "lng":-71.85626990
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":40.4959080,
                  "lng":-79.76214379999999
               }
            },
            "location":{
               "lat":43.29942850,
               "lng":-74.21793260000001
            },
            "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":45.01261130,
                  "lng":-71.85626990
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":40.4959080,
                  "lng":-79.76214379999999
               }
            }
         },
         "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
         ]
      },
      {
         "address_components":[
            {
               "long_name":"United States",
               "short_name":"US",
               "types":[
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"United States",
         "geometry":{
            "bounds":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":71.3898880,
                  "lng":-66.94976079999999
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":18.91106420,
                  "lng":172.45469660
               }
            },
            "location":{
               "lat":37.090240,
               "lng":-95.7128910
            },
            "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":49.380,
                  "lng":-66.940
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":25.820,
                  "lng":-124.390
               }
            }
         },
         "types":[
            "country",
            "political"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status":"OK"
}
```

My Java Source Code :

[Source Code with Output Link](http://pastebin.com/WujskkAJ)

I' m getting India, but I have to print **Vasant Vihar** in output.

Can anyone help me with some pieces of code for achieving this ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get `long_name` from current json String as:

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject("YOUR_JSON_STRING");

 JSONArray ja = json.getJSONArray("results");

for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

  JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

  JSONArray jaa = jo.getJSONArray("address_components");
  for (int j = 0; j < jaa.length(); j++) {

    JSONObject jotwo = jaa.getJSONObject(j);

       //long_name
       String str_long_name=jotwo.getString("long_name");
   }

}
```

Comment: Your code is working pretty well. But I got India in output and I've to print Vasant Vihar (Area Name). I've edited my question with my source code and output link, please review this.

Comment: @ManishAndroid : give me your json link because i think u are getting difference json string

Comment: Check this link :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding
On this page, there is a JSON URL which I used.

Comment: This is link what I'm using :
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=28.563676300000000000,77.162895899999960000&sensor=true

Comment: @ManishAndroid : i known about this but im asking what json you are getting just paste it in pastbin and give me link

Comment: I don't know exact position and area name, so how can I get data at particular position in an array list. Because I have to pass different latitude and longitude in methods parameters.

Comment: @ManishAndroid : you will need to parse lat also to get value from ArrayList

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Actually My application will work as below :
1. Android mobile user will send location to server.
2. On server, this java code will convert lat and long to address and find out area name from JSON.
3. Send this area name to android app again.

Comment: @ManishAndroid : im not able to understand what u are asking . best why is make an new fresh question for current issue to solve it quickly if my answer help u in parsing relevant values from json String then mark it as answer. Thanks

Comment: hey i have another array inside the `address_components` how to extract them? should i add another for loop inside ` for (int j = 0; j < jaa.length(); j++)` loop?

Answer (score 4):

I would rather recommend using [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for parsing into beans. You can choose the fields of interest to you.

Here are the beans I propose you to use:

The response class:

```
public class Response {
private Result [] results;
// getters and setters(optional)
}
```

The result class:

```
public class Result{
private AddressComponent[] addressComponents;
// getters and setters(optional)
}
```

The address component class:

```
public class AddressComponent {
private String longName;
private String shortName;
private String [] types;
// getters and setters (optional)
}
```

And here is how you parse:

```
String str = "<the ugly json you pasted>";
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
     .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES )
     .create();
```

**GSON by default ignores all json attributes that do not have corresponding Java fields.**

Response response = gson.fromJson(str, Response .class);

And you access the field of interest like that:

```
AddressComponent [] AddressComponents = response.getResults()[1].getAddressComponent();
```

Ok from now on you use the object as you wish.